# Avoiding Giving Maaserot?

Tags: halacha, maaser-tithes, agriculture

The Gemara in Bava Kama 28a says:

ת"ש בעל הבית שהניח פאה מצד אחד ובאו עניים ונטלו מצד אחר זה וזה פאה וא"א עביד איניש דינא לנפשיה אמאי זה וזה פאה לנקוט פזר וליתיב אמר רבא מאי זה וזה פאה לפוטרן מן המעשר כדתניא המפקיר את כרמו והשכים בבקר ובצרו חייב בפרט ובעוללות ובשכחה ובפאה ופטור מן המעשר

(Translation of the relevant part): What is meant by the ruling of: This produce and that produce are both considered pe’a? It means that they are considered pe’a with regard to exempting both portions of produce from tithes. Just as the portion that the poor people took is exempt from tithes, so is the portion that he allocated initially. This is as it is taught in a baraita: In the case of one who renounces ownership of his vineyard and arose early in the morning before anyone else took possession of it and harvested it, the one who renounces ownership is obligated in the mitzva of individual fallen grapes left for the poor [peret], and in the mitzva of incompletely formed clusters of grapes left for the poor [olelot], and in the mitzva of forgotten clusters of grapes left for the poor, and in the mitzva of pe’a, the four gifts to the poor that the Torah requires one to give from a vineyard (see Leviticus 19:9–10). But he is exempt from the mitzva to tithe his produce, because this requirement does not apply to an ownerless field. Likewise, in the above case the portion of the field that was allocated for pe’a is exempt from tithes even after the owner reclaims it, as pe’a is considered ownerless property in this regard.

Rashi explains here that even though the owner reclaimed the part of the field he designated as pe'ah, it is exempt from ma'aserot (דאף פאה הנשארת הפקר חשיבא ואע"ג דנקט לה איהו פטורה ממעשר).

So couldn't a person theoretically designate 99% of his field as pe'ah (since one can't designate all of it, as per Tosefta Peah 1:1) and then reclaim all of it (excluding the part that actually needs to be given as pe'ah, i.e., 1/60th of his field) and thereby be exempt from giving ma'aser except on that 1%?

Comment: Why go through so much trouble? Just harvest normally and bring it through any entrance but the main one when you bring it into the granary. Without Meiruach, you don’t need to give ma’aser. If you’re asking whether this particular ploy would work, technically, yes (I think), though anybody could take from that 99% before you’re done with it. For that reason, it’s not the most effective cop-out. You forget that one is guaranteed wealth from at least two Biblical sources off the top of my head for giving ma’aser - cop-outs are to your detriment. As a Levi, I’m sort of biased, though. :)

Comment: @DonielF How does bringing it through a side entrance exempt one from ma'aser? Also, I suspect it doesn't take much time to declare something pe'ah, and then to reclaim it by a similar declaration...

Comment: Once it’s peah, it’s ownerless. You can’t just say it’s yours - you have to do an actual acquisition on it. As for the side door, I don’t have time to get the sources at the moment, but there’s a concept called meiruach, that the produce must be “complete” to be subject to the laws of Terumah and Ma’aser. One requirement to being complete is that it’s brought through the main entrance.

Comment: By the way, this Halacha, that Peah is exempt from Terumah and Ma’aser, is an explicit Mishnah (Peah 1:6, Terumos 1:5, the former of Which makes reference to the Meiruach concept I mentioned above).

Comment: @DonielF How would you go about re-acquiring the field? And also where can I read more about this side door business?

Comment: Well, you still own the field, so it’s just the crops you have to worry about. You’d do that by gathering the crops. But what just occurred to me is that Peah is reserved for the poor - unless this guy has less than 200 zuz in spite of his field, he isn’t allowed to take his crop back once he’s designated it Peah. Another thing that just occurred to me is that you’re able to give a gift to someone on condition that it’s not eligible for ma’aser. He should be able to give his field as a gift to someone on condition that they give it back to him on condition that he not take ma’aser.

Comment: @DonielF But it seems from the Gemara that he can reclaim it as long as something else is designated for pe'ah.

Comment: Ah. Now I get what you’re asking. That’s not at all what the Braisa is saying. The second Braisa, the one about the vineyard, speaks of a case where he harvested his field he designated as ownerless. The first Braisa speaks of a case where he designated one patch as Peah and the poor took from another patch; as the second Braisa is brought to explain the first, the first must mean that it was originally ownerless and he reacquired it as well, once the second patch was designated Peah in its stead.

Comment: The point of both is that once it was at some point ownerless, it loses its chiyuv ma’aser permanently. (See Tosfos, who explain the Peah case slightly differently in accordance with Beis Hillel. We pasken like Beis Shamai on this one, as we go by the stam Mishnah in Peah 1:6 against Beis Hillel’s opinion in 6:1, and so I have been explaining accordingly.)

Comment: @DonielF Tosfot says ומייתי ראיה דבשביל שחזר וזכה בו לא מחייבינן כיון דמתחילה פאה גמורה היתה ונפטרה ופאה דמיפטרא מן המעשר לא מטעם הפקר...it's patur from ma'aser because he designated it as pe'ah, and not because it was ownerless...

Comment: Right. Like I said, Tosfos are explaining Beis Hillel, as they say earlier in that piece. I was explaining according to Beis Shammai.

Comment: @DonielF "We pasken like Beis Shamai on this one, as we go by the stam Mishnah in Peah 1:6 against Beis Hillel’s opinion in 6:1"...how did you get that we follow Beis Shammai from Peah 1:6? The Mishnah says that Peah is pattur from ma'aser as is hefker, which implies that hefker is not the same as peah, and thus hefker is only when it is available to the rich as well (unlike peah), as Beis Hillel claims in 6:1?

Comment: See Tiferes Yisrael there. Sorry - should have quoted him earlier. He goes through the sugya and concludes that the stam Mishnah accords with Beis Shammai in 6:1.

Comment: Then according to Beis Shammai what's the difference between declaring something hefker and declaring more produce to be pe'ah?

Comment: Excuse me - I misquoted. It was the Meleches Shlomo in the name of the Yerushalmi who made this inference. As 1:6 opens with “always” that indicates that even if he designated Peah and then retracted that declaration, that portion is patur from Ma’aser (as in the Gemara in BK). That’s exactly the opinion of Beis Shammai, who says that Hefker just for the poor is Hefker. Apparently the only difference is whether it counts to Peah, but in respect to everything else it’s identical.

Comment: At this point I think enough sources have been brought to sufficiently answer your question - I’ll get to that later when I have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed a correct deduction: one who designates part of his field as Pe’ah and then retracts that declaration does not need to give Ma’aser on that which was formerly Pe’ah. Sort of.

The Mishnah in Pe’ah 1:6 says:

> **לְעוֹלָם** הוּא נוֹתֵן מִשּׁוּם פֵּאָה וּפָטוּר מִן הַמַּעַשְׂרוֹת, עַד שֶׁיְּמָרֵחַ.
>
> **Always** he can give because of Pe’ah and it is exempt from Ma’aser, until he smooths it.

Says the Meleches Shlomo ad. loc.:

> לעולם הוא נותן משום פאה כו'. בירושל' מתני' דקתני לעולם הוא נותן משום פאה לעולם משמע אפי' לאחר שהפריש חובת הפאה דהיינו א' מס' חוזר ומוסיף ואותו תוס' פטור מן המעשרות. אתיא כב"ש דאמר לק' רפ"ו הפקר לעניים הפקר ופטור וכן פאה זו שהוסיף והפקירה לעניים פטורה אבל לבעה"ב חייבת אא"כ הפקירה אף לעשירים כן פי' ר"ש ז"ל:
>
> From the Yerushalmi: Our Mishnah which teaches “‘Always’ he can give because of Pe’ah” - “Always” implies that even after he separates Pe’ah, i.e. 1/60, and then adds it back to his field, that addition is still exempt from Ma’aser. This accords with the opinion of Beis Shammai, who says later in the beginning of the sixth Perek that one may designate something as Hefker only for the poor and thereby exempt it from Ma’aser. Likewise this Pe’ah which he previously designated as Hefker for the poor is exempt from Ma’aser. The owner, however, must still take off Ma’aser until he designates it as Hefker even for the rich.

Hence, the Mishnah’s statement that it’s exempt “until he smooths it,” i.e. Meiruach, the classical threshold (pardon the pun) for when it’s obligated in Ma’aser.

Comment: "The owner, however, must still take off Ma’aser until he designates it as Hefker even for the rich." So does this mean that additional pe'ah (i.e., hefker for the poor) is exempt from ma'aserot as long as it remains that way but if he reclaims it then the only way it can be exempt from ma'aserot is if it was also hefker for the rich before he reclaimed it?

Comment: @Gabriel Correct

Comment: Where does he get that from?

Comment: @Gabriel See my final paragraph - from the fact that he’s only bought himself time before he has to take off Ma’aser.

Comment: So how come when he's mafkir it and then he reclaims it it is still pattur from ma'aser but when he sets it aside as pe'ah and then reclaims it it is subject to ma'aser once the time of meiruach passes? Shouldn't the idea of "once exempt always exempt" apply in the case of pe'ah too?

Comment: The difference is *for whom* it is Hefker. If he was mafkir it for the poor only, it would be identical. The point is that whoever has a right to it when it’s Hefker does not have to take Ma’aser: thus, the rich farmer must ultimately take Ma’aser in the case of Pe’ah or Hefker l’aniyim, but if it’s Hefker for everyone, rich included, the farmer need not take Ma’aser at all.